# Is there any way in Outlook threaded view to show email count as a column?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have Outlook 2013 and I use threaded view.  In some cases a row represents just one email and in other cases it shows a threaded conversation that has 100 emails within it.  Is there anyway to show a column that shows email count in the thread?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to achieve this. At least within Outlook, no option to add a column to show count for emails.